# How and why center residuals when doing time-series bootstrap?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, bootstrap, residuals, autoregressive

I am trying to understand and implement Sieve bootstrap (maybe also known s a parametric or model based bootstrap) for time series, where the bootstrap samples are sampled from centered fitted residuals. The actual centering step is not clear to me, what does it actually do, and why is it there?

The method is introduced in: Peter Bühlmann. "Sieve bootstrap for time series." Bernoulli 3 (2) 123 - 148, June 1997. https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-3/issue-2/Sieve-bootstrap-for-time-series/bj/1177526726.full

The part that describe the centering is between eq. 2.2 and 2.3:

[image]

where p is model order of the AR model and n is the length of the time serie